# After login in user want to remove the user registeration part from header

Tags: php

After loginin user I want to remove the user registration link  and changing "signin" to "logout" from the header and rest will remain the same. Do I have to create a new header for that which do not contain user register part and call it when session is start or their is some other method.

header.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="page_style.css" type="text/css" />
<div class="container">
<div id="header">
<div id="header_text">
   <b><a href="div_tuts.php">Home</a></b>
   <b><a href="aboutus.php">AboutUs</a></b>
   <b><a href="register.php"><?php if(empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        echo "Register";} ?></a></b>
       <?php
       if (empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
            { 
            echo '<a href="login.php">SignIn</a>';
            }
       else 
            {
            echo '<b><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></b>';
            }
            ?>
       <b><a href="contactus.php">ContactUS</a></b>
</div>
</div>

<div id="main">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: Have you heard about php session?

Comment: Yes I know that, but I was little confuse how to use it in coding.I have updated my code see if it is right way to implement or not

Answer (score 2):

On successfully login, register a session value like bellow,

```
     $_SESSION['isUser']=TRUE;
```

Now, change your above HTML Content as,

```
        <div class="container">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="header_text">
                    <b><a href="div_tuts.php">Home</a></b>
                    <b><a href="aboutus.php">AboutUs</a></b> 
                    <?php
                    if ($_SESSION['isUser'])
                        echo '<b><a href="logout.php">SignOut</a></b>';
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<b><a href="register.php">Register</a></b>';
                        echo '<b><a href="login.php">SignIn</a></b>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <b><a href="contactus.php">ContactUS</a></b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main">

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I have updated my code see if it is right way to implement or not.

Answer (score 1):

First initialize session and if user is login set the session variable `$_SESSION['login']` and then Try this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="page_style.css" type="text/css" />
<div class="container">
<div id="header">
<div id="header_text">
   <b><a href="div_tuts.php">Home</a></b>
   <b><a href="aboutus.php">AboutUs</a></b>
   <b><a href="register.php">Register</a></b>
   <b><a href="login.php"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) echo "Logout";
                                else    echo "SignIn"; ?></a></b>
   <b><a href="contactus.php">ContactUS</a></b>
</div>
</div>

<div id="main">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @dakshbhatt.I have updated my code see if it is right way to implement or not

Comment: @wek : I don't find any update in your code, please check it again.

Comment: done please see again

Comment: @wek : use `isset()` instead of `empty()`, it will throw an error when your variable is not set.